# KEGG FTP vs KEGG API

Tags: database, kegg

I was reading the KEGG [plea](https://www.kegg.jp/kegg/docs/plea.html) and I found that it doesn't forbid using the KEGG API. Then, what is in the FTP server [license for personal use/academic use](https://www.bioinformatics.jp/docs/subscription_personal.pdf) that it is not covered by the API?

Or I could download all the database via the API?

PS: I couldn't find how to download which genes are in which pathways but it might be I didn't expend enough time with the queries.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the way to download the [genes and pathways](http://rest.kegg.jp/link/pathway/hsa) thanks to this answer using [KEGGREST](https://support.bioconductor.org/p/109871/#109959).

It seems that the [API](https://www.kegg.jp/kegg/rest/keggapi.html) allows to fully download the database because it allows to download info, list, find, get, conv, link, ddi.

In fact in the message of 2011-05-21 it mentions that the API includes more options to download the KGML files that previously where only possible to get via the FTP site.

Answer (score 1):

If you like to get pathways and corresponding genes as simple table format in a plain text file, use [GeneSCF](https://www.biostars.org/p/108669/) 'prepare_database' module. This can be simple solution.

**FTP vs API**:

The differences I see is,

- quick access to the updated content via FTP. With that I assume using [FTP version](https://www.bioinformatics.jp/en/keggftp.html) you will have access to weekly database updates. Also bulk download is possible and more convenient via FTP subscription.
- But [KEGG REST API](https://www.kegg.jp/kegg/rest/) updates once in month or two months or a year (not a recently updated contents).

Comment: Thanks for your reply, and welcome to the site! That's the kind of information I use but not what I was asking about. But GeneSCF assumes it can access the **whole** KEGG database via API. Could you confirm it?

Comment: It uses KEGG REST (https://www.kegg.jp/kegg/rest/keggapi.html) to access data only for specified organism. It never stores or reterives whole KEGG database. Check out [GeneSCF publication] (https://bmcbioinformatics.biomedcentral.com/articles/10.1186/s12859-016-1250-z) for complete details of workflow.

Comment: I've read the relevant parts of it and it didn't answer my question.

Comment: Sorry if that did not answer your question. I thought I answered "**PS: I couldn't find how to download which genes are in which pathways but it might be I didn't expend enough time with the queries.**" this part. Good luck.

Comment: Oh, that got already answered in the other answer. Thanks, and my apologies

Comment: So, the API data is not updated at the same time that the FTP files. That's interesting: Is there any written documentation about this to read more about it?

Comment: You click those links I provided. You will get an idea about what I mentioned. There is no direct statement but if you compare those two pages, that's the information I get.

Comment: I must miss the point, I can only confirm the weekly updated KEGG FTP (on Tuesday JST) , not the update frequency of the KEGG REST API data. Anyway, thanks for your patience (I won't bother you more).

Answer (score -1):

We implemented [Bio2BEL KEGG](https://github.com/bio2bel/kegg) package to download the KEGG database via its RESTful API

Comment: Welcome to the site Daniel. Thanks for sharing! I was reading the ComPath article precisely now. But I was not asking if it is possible to download data, but if it is possible to download *all* the database via the API, which apparently it is possible.